# VHDL Quartus Does Not Recognize "+" and "-"

Tags: vhdl, quartus

So i have tried to make a program that performs either addition or substractions following a simple condition but my VHDL compiler keeps telling me that it can't recognize what "+" and "-" are for.
  I'm also not sure about the library i'm using.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY ADDSUBS IS
PORT( CNTRL: in std_logic;
      NUM1, NUM2: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      SUM: out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0));
END ADDSUBS;

ARCHITECTURE A4 OF ADDSUBS IS
BEGIN
SUM <= ('0' & NUM1) + ('0' & NUM2) WHEN (CNTRL='0') ELSE
       ('0' & NUM1) - ('0' & NUM2) WHEN (CNTRL='1');
END;
```

Comment: Without using the -2008 IEEE package numeric_std_unsigned `SUM <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & NUM1) + unsigned('0' & NUM2)) WHEN (CNTRL='0') ELSE
       std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & NUM1) - unsigned('0' & NUM2)) WHEN (CNTRL='1');`. std_logic_vector is not a numeric type while type unsigned represents a binary numeric type. Package ieee.numeric_std_unsigned provides the same operations for std_logic_vector as provided for type unsigned. Values of types std_logic_vector and unsigned are closely related and eligible for type conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You havent included any packages that can do arithmatic with std_logic_vectors. ('0' & NUM1) is still a std_logic_vector, you need to cast it to an unsigned/signed:

```
unsigned('0' & NUM1)
```

Comment: That has worked for me, also something that works is using the STD_LOGIC_(UN)SIGNED library to specify which the compiler should consider.

Comment: the std_logic_(un)signed libraries are non-standard VHDL and the general recommendation is to avoid using them. VHDL 2008 adds the numeric_std_unsigned (no signed version) if you want unsigned arithmatic with slvs.